# Rabbitmq tracing: Unable to enable on management console

Tags: rabbitmq

I enabled tracing, using,

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_tracing
rabbitmqctl trace_on

rabbitmq-plugins list
[E] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.1.1
```

However I dont see the plugins under the admin tab. I'm using 3.1.1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installed the plug-in,  you have to restart RabbitMQ.
Then the plug-in will be available to the console.

Before restart the command `rabbitmq-plugins list` shows `[E] rabbitmq_tracing` but is not available to the console.